# Хороши ли ссылки mailto для спама

Tags: seo, html, css

Действительно ли так хороши для спам ботов ссылки типа `<a href="mailto:mail@mail.ru">E-mail</a>` и как можно защитить свой ящик от спам ботов.

Вариант заменить email картинкой отпадает. Также нужно сделать БЕЗ использования JS. Это очень важное условие

Comment: Я не понимаю суть вопроса. Подробнее пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, если на странице есть такая ссылка, и страница попадёт боту-сканеру, вытащить из неё email не представляет проблем.

Если хотите, чтобы на ваш ящик не приходил спам -- не оставляйте ваш адрес в местах, доступных ботам. Например, в интернете :)

Защититься от умного бота нельзя: есть даже особо умные, которые разгадывают капчу. А уж пробежаться регулярным выражением по странице может любой школьник, даже я.

Comment: Дело в том, что я сделал сайт портфолио. И в шапке красуется такая ссылка с моим e-mail. Вот надо от спама бы защититься

Comment: @inferus: абсолютной защиты нету. Можно только попытаться усложнить боту жизнь и надеяться, что его автор ленив. Всё, что увидит человек, увидит и бот. Особенного пространства для манёвра нету, раз вы не хотите js.

Comment: Расскажи плиз, как усложнить)

Comment: @inferus: ну например, проверять валидность заголовков. Проверять скорость перехода между страницами. В общем, пытаться "поймать" бот на поведении, нетипичном для людей. Положить невидимую для людей ссылку и тех, кто по ней перейдёт, считать ботом. И т. п.

Comment: Да я думаю с gmail проблем со спамом не будет, я свой адрес публикую открыто почти на всех сайтах где регистрируюсь, корме 1 письма в день ничего спамного не приходит, больше мучаюсь с рассылками, а вот с mail.ru бывали проблемы со спамом.

Comment: @Ъь_ не нужно идеализировать детище гугля, мой адрес вообще ни где не светился, зато предложение от беглых арабских мультимилиардеров приходят каждый день.
или поздравление с выигрышем миллиона долларов.

Answer (score 2):

При проектировании защиты нужно исходить из того, что никакая защита не должна создавать неудобств пользователю. Пользователь должен иметь возможность:

1. получить нормальную реакцию по клику
       на ссылке (запуск обработчика
       mailto:)
2. прочитать e-mail, не ломая глаза
3. скопировать e-mail, как из
       контекстного меню, так и выделяя
       текст мышкой (то есть всякие извращения с некликабельными ссылками, вставкой пробелов или заменой символа @ на "(at)", "собака" etc - мимо)

Всем требованиям удовлетворяет только, пожалуй, обфускация ссылки при помощи JavaScript (ну, со своими недостатками). Нужно ли заморачиваться этим - решать вам. Моё мнение такое: не стоит оно того в принципе. Уже не те времена, когда за трафик на модеме в 2400 бод платить нужно было, да и спам-фильтры на что?

Comment: Пожалуй оставлю, как есть)

Answer (score 0):

Для защиты ссылок `mailto:` от спам-ботов пользуюсь инструментом обфускации при помощи JavaScript'а [MailLink](http://webdevtools.ru/maillink). Преимущества:

1. [Высокая эффективность метода](https://habrahabr.ru/post/22549/),
2. Отсутствие неудобств, описанных [в ответе ув-мого user6550](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/171352/199934),
3. В отличии от прочих аналогичных сервисов присутствует возможность вставлять тему письма по умолчанию и текст ссылки — любые слово или фразу, при клике по которым пользователь переходит к отправке сообщения на Ваш электронный ящик.

Несмотря на то, что это [создаёт больше проблем, чем пользы, и разработчики браузеров убрали настройку куда подальше](http://beginpc.ru/internet/zachem-nuzhen-javascript), некоторые по тем или иным причинам запрещают выполнение скриптов на страницах. Специально для них сразу после закрывающего тега `</script>` нашей обфусцированной ссылки добавляем следующий текст:

```
<noscript>[Включите в браузере JavaScript для возможности связаться по электронной почте]</noscript>
```

Теперь пользователи с отключенным JS на месте, где должна располагаться ссылка, увидят надпись `[Включите в браузере JavaScript для возможности связаться по электронной почте]`. Если им необходимо связаться с Вами по почте, пусть [временно изменят настройки браузера](https://yandex.ru/support/common/browsers-settings/browsers-java-js-settings.xml).

Спасибо.

[image: Скриншот MailLink]